# Angular does not recognise a selector

Tags: angular

I am confused right now. Trying to display a component in this way:

```
<popup-standard></popup-standard>
```

popup-standard.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: "[popup-standard]",
    templateUrl: "./standard.template.html"
})
export class PopupStandardComponent { }
```

popups.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        PopupStandardComponent,
    ],
    exports: [
        PopupStandardComponent
    ]
})
export class PopupsModule { }
```

Added PopupsModule in my module `imports`:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        ROUTES,
        RouterModule,
        PopupsModule,
        MockModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        ChatComponent,
        LayoutComponent
    ],

})
```

Showing the two errors:

- If popup-standard is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
- If popup-standard is a Web Component then add CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA to the @NgModule.schemas of this component to suppress this message.

Even if I add schema CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA to my module the error is gone but component is empty even if there is some html code etc.

here is package dependencies:

```
"@angular/animations": "^4.2.6",
"@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
"@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
"jquery": "^3.1.0",
"rxjs": "^5.1.0",
"zone.js": "^0.8.4"
```

I think I am doing it in right way but somehow it doesn't.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `selector: "popup-standard",`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be just

```
@Component({
    selector: "popup-standard",
    templateUrl: "./standard.template.html"
})
```

Comment: I overlooked it. Thanks for quick answer.